# Removing Border Outline in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm implementing a toggle widget and in an attempt to make the borders round, I now seem to have border outlines. I'm not quite sure how to disable them. [image]

As you can see, next to "Bug" you have the square corner outlines.

My code:

```
Container(
      height: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
      child: ToggleButtons(
        isSelected: isSelected,
        selectedColor: Colors.orange[600],
        color: Colors.black,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
              child: Text('Bug',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18))),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
              child: Text('Improvement', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18))),
        ]
```

Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement i have created a custom design please check and let me know if it works

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isItemSelected = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 40,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isItemSelected = !_isItemSelected;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                    height: 35,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color:
                          _isItemSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      boxShadow: _isItemSelected
                          ? [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                                blurRadius: 7,
                                offset:
                                    Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                              ),
                            ]
                          : null,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      'Bugs',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: _isItemSelected
                            ? Colors.orangeAccent
                            : Colors.blueGrey,
                      ),
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isItemSelected = !_isItemSelected;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 35,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color:
                          !_isItemSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      boxShadow: !_isItemSelected
                          ? [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                                blurRadius: 7,
                                offset:
                                    Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                              ),
                            ]
                          : null,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      "Improvements",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: !_isItemSelected
                            ? Colors.orangeAccent
                            : Colors.blueGrey,
                      ),
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Check the image that i have added.
[image]

Comment: That did work, thank you. Side question if you don't mind, any idea how to shorten the bar? As you can see in the image, the bar it too long for the two text fields.

Comment: which bar you are taking about, did not get you. can you elaborate

Comment: Bug and Improvement are both fields inside a long grey bar. The grey bar is too long, and I want to make it align with the size of "Bug" and "Improvement" (see image).

Comment: Can you show the parent widget of this container what you using this in row or column, and i have made some more changes for the border add this line  disabledBorderColor: Colors.transparent,

Comment: There is no parent widget, it basically starts like this: ```Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(```. Not really sure how to convert this into row/column since I'm using the default ToggleButtons by Flutter

Comment: check the edit that i have made, is this what you are accepting

Comment: Hey Sagar, I've added an example picture to my original post of what I'm trying to get to :P

Comment: hey @someJoe121 i see you can do this in simple manner, there is no need for the Toggle button i have created an example for this one let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, have a nice day happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
```

Remove that code from your Container